# MDADM Raid10 event mismatch after restart

Tags: debian, mdadm, xfs

I made a raid10 with 8x8TB drives the file system on it is XFS. I never had any issue with it. The raid is configured as near2 and internal bitmap. The drives are connected to a LSI-9211-8i in HBA mode.

Last week, I finally bought another set of 8x8TB drive, because the raid was full. Here is how I did to add that to my existing RAID :

1. Tested the drive using smartctl (no problem).
2. Created a new GPT partition tab and a XFS partition on each drive.
3. Used the command `sudo mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/...` to add the drives.
4. Grew the array by doing `sudo mdadm --grow /dev/md0 --size=max`. It took first 2 days to reshape and then a day to resync. It went  succesfully without any error or interruption. After that the raid was clean and active.
5. Resized the file system with `sudo xfs_grow /dev/md0`. It completed without any issue.
6. Mounted the raid array and tested it. It was working fine. I resstarted the server to be sure, the array was still clean.

So then what happened?!
I used the array to download new stuff using Radarr, Sonarr, Deluge (all in docker). I had to restart the server (I do that once a week to free ressources) and then something happened.

The raid array was now inactive (check below for mdadm detail). The event count was wrong on 4 out of 16 drives. After multiples attempt I manage to bring it back by doing `sudo mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sd[...]`. I tested the XFS filesystem with `sudo xfs_repair -n /dev/md0`, pfiou... Everything seemed OK.

By curiosity, I tried to restart again today, I made sure the docker container was closed. I checked the array is was clean, so I wait 5 minutes and I did `sudo reboot`. Same thing happened again!! This time 6 drives where out of sync for the event count... So again I did the same as above and it seems fine, but now I am very worried since I currently have nothing to back that up (I know it's bad).

Do you guys may have any idea of what is hapening? 
Thank you in advance for all of your help! :)

`sudo mdadm --examine...` before I re-assembled again :

```
/dev/sda1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : d9b2f19f:01d7ce88:c46d2dd3:c1ab05f0
           Name : Server:0
  Creation Time : Fri Mar 29 16:19:52 2019
     Raid Level : raid10
   Raid Devices : 16

 Avail Dev Size : 15627789312 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
     Array Size : 62511153152 (59615.28 GiB 64011.42 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 15627788288 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
    Data Offset : 261120 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=260976 sectors, after=1024 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 17c3e75a:d0360875:69201f88:cababd94

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Wed Mar 25 00:27:04 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 128 sectors
       Checksum : b8d092ad - correct
         Events : 63706

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 12
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdb1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : d9b2f19f:01d7ce88:c46d2dd3:c1ab05f0
           Name : Server:0
  Creation Time : Fri Mar 29 16:19:52 2019
     Raid Level : raid10
   Raid Devices : 16

 Avail Dev Size : 15627789312 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
     Array Size : 62511153152 (59615.28 GiB 64011.42 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 15627788288 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
    Data Offset : 261120 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=260976 sectors, after=1024 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : c0f6cf6d:3c5687e3:8a745314:9fcd0ea6

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Wed Mar 25 00:27:16 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 128 sectors
       Checksum : d79a4cca - correct
         Events : 63709

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 11
   Array State : .AA.A.AA.AAA.AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdc1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : d9b2f19f:01d7ce88:c46d2dd3:c1ab05f0
           Name : Server:0
  Creation Time : Fri Mar 29 16:19:52 2019
     Raid Level : raid10
   Raid Devices : 16

 Avail Dev Size : 15627789312 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
     Array Size : 62511153152 (59615.28 GiB 64011.42 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 15627788288 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
    Data Offset : 261120 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=260976 sectors, after=1024 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 1c3c8784:6b6bcbef:4ce604b6:5734fed2

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Wed Mar 25 00:27:04 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 128 sectors
       Checksum : c9597fc2 - correct
         Events : 63706

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 8
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdd1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : d9b2f19f:01d7ce88:c46d2dd3:c1ab05f0
           Name : Server:0
  Creation Time : Fri Mar 29 16:19:52 2019
     Raid Level : raid10
   Raid Devices : 16

 Avail Dev Size : 15627789312 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
     Array Size : 62511153152 (59615.28 GiB 64011.42 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 15627788288 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
    Data Offset : 261120 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=260976 sectors, after=1024 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : f650167a:562c413d:22d8ba5f:f6f4e486

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Wed Mar 25 00:27:16 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 128 sectors
       Checksum : 69d80807 - correct
         Events : 63709

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 13
   Array State : .AA.A.AA.AAA.AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sde1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : d9b2f19f:01d7ce88:c46d2dd3:c1ab05f0
           Name : Server:0
  Creation Time : Fri Mar 29 16:19:52 2019
     Raid Level : raid10
   Raid Devices : 16

 Avail Dev Size : 15627789312 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
     Array Size : 62511153152 (59615.28 GiB 64011.42 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 15627788288 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
    Data Offset : 261120 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=260976 sectors, after=1024 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 8397c880:8807eb34:75425522:4f1c2f37

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Wed Mar 25 00:27:16 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 128 sectors
       Checksum : db18bb75 - correct
         Events : 63709

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 9
   Array State : .AA.A.AA.AAA.AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdf1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : d9b2f19f:01d7ce88:c46d2dd3:c1ab05f0
           Name : Server:0
  Creation Time : Fri Mar 29 16:19:52 2019
     Raid Level : raid10
   Raid Devices : 16

 Avail Dev Size : 15627789312 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
     Array Size : 62511153152 (59615.28 GiB 64011.42 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 15627788288 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
    Data Offset : 261120 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=260976 sectors, after=1024 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : cb43d48b:862f335a:90bddcd7:9060894b

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Wed Mar 25 00:27:16 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 128 sectors
       Checksum : d54e4f12 - correct
         Events : 63709

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 15
   Array State : .AA.A.AA.AAA.AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdg1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : d9b2f19f:01d7ce88:c46d2dd3:c1ab05f0
           Name : Server:0
  Creation Time : Fri Mar 29 16:19:52 2019
     Raid Level : raid10
   Raid Devices : 16

 Avail Dev Size : 15627789312 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
     Array Size : 62511153152 (59615.28 GiB 64011.42 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 15627788288 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
    Data Offset : 261120 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=260976 sectors, after=1024 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 602c75b6:00d68a1f:c04c404f:514bffed

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Wed Mar 25 00:27:16 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 128 sectors
       Checksum : df205817 - correct
         Events : 63709

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 10
   Array State : .AA.A.AA.AAA.AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdh1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : d9b2f19f:01d7ce88:c46d2dd3:c1ab05f0
           Name : Server:0
  Creation Time : Fri Mar 29 16:19:52 2019
     Raid Level : raid10
   Raid Devices : 16

 Avail Dev Size : 15627789312 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
     Array Size : 62511153152 (59615.28 GiB 64011.42 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 15627788288 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
    Data Offset : 261120 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=260976 sectors, after=1024 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : b8db9412:ae32feaa:4d330c95:5cdcd294

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Wed Mar 25 00:27:16 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 128 sectors
       Checksum : b352dbb1 - correct
         Events : 63709

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 14
   Array State : .AA.A.AA.AAA.AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdi1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : d9b2f19f:01d7ce88:c46d2dd3:c1ab05f0
           Name : Server:0
  Creation Time : Fri Mar 29 16:19:52 2019
     Raid Level : raid10
   Raid Devices : 16

 Avail Dev Size : 15627789312 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
     Array Size : 62511153152 (59615.28 GiB 64011.42 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 15627788288 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
    Data Offset : 261120 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=260992 sectors, after=1024 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 4af973aa:e4ae2676:67017e23:343e8114

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Wed Mar 25 00:27:04 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : 249da51a - correct
         Events : 63706

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdj1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : d9b2f19f:01d7ce88:c46d2dd3:c1ab05f0
           Name : Server:0
  Creation Time : Fri Mar 29 16:19:52 2019
     Raid Level : raid10
   Raid Devices : 16

 Avail Dev Size : 15627789312 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
     Array Size : 62511153152 (59615.28 GiB 64011.42 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 15627788288 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
    Data Offset : 261120 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=260992 sectors, after=1024 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 35255445:73245125:1e05a845:0b213eca

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Wed Mar 25 00:27:04 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : 468f2d21 - correct
         Events : 63706

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdl1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : d9b2f19f:01d7ce88:c46d2dd3:c1ab05f0
           Name : Server:0
  Creation Time : Fri Mar 29 16:19:52 2019
     Raid Level : raid10
   Raid Devices : 16

 Avail Dev Size : 15627789312 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
     Array Size : 62511153152 (59615.28 GiB 64011.42 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 15627788288 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
    Data Offset : 261120 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=260992 sectors, after=1024 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : f1af8db7:4e256b3b:bdc65518:b26bb193

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Wed Mar 25 00:27:16 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : 6ae0c513 - correct
         Events : 63709

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 4
   Array State : .AA.A.AA.AAA.AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdm1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : d9b2f19f:01d7ce88:c46d2dd3:c1ab05f0
           Name : Server:0
  Creation Time : Fri Mar 29 16:19:52 2019
     Raid Level : raid10
   Raid Devices : 16

 Avail Dev Size : 15627789312 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
     Array Size : 62511153152 (59615.28 GiB 64011.42 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 15627788288 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
    Data Offset : 261120 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=260992 sectors, after=1024 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : e2b66811:4f48ebc6:245f75c2:c64db0c6

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Wed Mar 25 00:27:16 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : 2d5a6983 - correct
         Events : 63709

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 6
   Array State : .AA.A.AA.AAA.AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdn1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : d9b2f19f:01d7ce88:c46d2dd3:c1ab05f0
           Name : Server:0
  Creation Time : Fri Mar 29 16:19:52 2019
     Raid Level : raid10
   Raid Devices : 16

 Avail Dev Size : 15627789312 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
     Array Size : 62511153152 (59615.28 GiB 64011.42 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 15627788288 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
    Data Offset : 261120 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=260992 sectors, after=1024 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : dd3f61c8:1ca69a95:d58a4ac2:c46365d0

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Wed Mar 25 00:27:04 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : bcaf91e8 - correct
         Events : 63706

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 5
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdo1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : d9b2f19f:01d7ce88:c46d2dd3:c1ab05f0
           Name : Server:0
  Creation Time : Fri Mar 29 16:19:52 2019
     Raid Level : raid10
   Raid Devices : 16

 Avail Dev Size : 15627789312 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
     Array Size : 62511153152 (59615.28 GiB 64011.42 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 15627788288 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
    Data Offset : 261120 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=260992 sectors, after=1024 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 7b867d58:c5b0551a:753ebe4f:9502faa5

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Wed Mar 25 00:27:04 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : 348f359d - correct
         Events : 63706

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 3
   Array State : AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdp1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : d9b2f19f:01d7ce88:c46d2dd3:c1ab05f0
           Name : Server:0
  Creation Time : Fri Mar 29 16:19:52 2019
     Raid Level : raid10
   Raid Devices : 16

 Avail Dev Size : 15627789312 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
     Array Size : 62511153152 (59615.28 GiB 64011.42 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 15627788288 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
    Data Offset : 261120 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=260992 sectors, after=1024 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 72a44102:13e98e3a:844d9e0b:e58637cc

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Wed Mar 25 00:27:16 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : e0871f55 - correct
         Events : 63709

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 7
   Array State : .AA.A.AA.AAA.AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sdq1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x1
     Array UUID : d9b2f19f:01d7ce88:c46d2dd3:c1ab05f0
           Name : Server:0
  Creation Time : Fri Mar 29 16:19:52 2019
     Raid Level : raid10
   Raid Devices : 16

 Avail Dev Size : 15627789312 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
     Array Size : 62511153152 (59615.28 GiB 64011.42 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 15627788288 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
    Data Offset : 261120 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=260992 sectors, after=1024 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 6b0152f0:ca1be94f:1af1ee36:e735cf70

Internal Bitmap : 8 sectors from superblock
    Update Time : Wed Mar 25 00:27:16 2020
  Bad Block Log : 512 entries available at offset 72 sectors
       Checksum : b3da0199 - correct
         Events : 63709

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 512K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : .AA.A.AA.AAA.AAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

`sudo mdadm -D /dev/md0` before I re-assembled again :

```
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
        Raid Level : raid0
     Total Devices : 16
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

             State : inactive
   Working Devices : 16

              Name : Server:0
              UUID : d9b2f19f:01d7ce88:c46d2dd3:c1ab05f0
            Events : 63709

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice

       -      65        1        -        /dev/sdq1
       -       8        1        -        /dev/sda1
       -       8      241        -        /dev/sdp1
       -       8      225        -        /dev/sdo1
       -       8      209        -        /dev/sdn1
       -       8      193        -        /dev/sdm1
       -       8      177        -        /dev/sdl1
       -       8      145        -        /dev/sdj1
       -       8      129        -        /dev/sdi1
       -       8      113        -        /dev/sdh1
       -       8       97        -        /dev/sdg1
       -       8       81        -        /dev/sdf1
       -       8       65        -        /dev/sde1
       -       8       49        -        /dev/sdd1
       -       8       33        -        /dev/sdc1
       -       8       17        -        /dev/sdb1
```

`cat /proc/mdstat` before I re-assembled again :

```
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : inactive sdc1[15](S) sdi1[1](S) sdo1[3](S) sdm1[6](S) sdl1[4](S) sdq1[2](S) sde1[14](S) sdh1[9](S) sdd1[10](S) sdj1[0](S) sdb1[12](S) sdg1[13](S) sdp1[7](S) sdf1[8](S) sdn1[5](S) sda1[11](S)
      125022314496 blocks super 1.2

unused devices: <none>
```

`sudo mdadm -D /dev/md0` after I re-assembled again (yes I launched a mdadm check in case) :

```
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Fri Mar 29 16:19:52 2019
        Raid Level : raid10
        Array Size : 62511153152 (59615.28 GiB 64011.42 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 7813894144 (7451.91 GiB 8001.43 GB)
      Raid Devices : 16
     Total Devices : 16
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

     Intent Bitmap : Internal

       Update Time : Wed Mar 25 04:28:53 2020
             State : clean, checking 
    Active Devices : 16
   Working Devices : 16
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

            Layout : near=2
        Chunk Size : 512K

Consistency Policy : bitmap

      Check Status : 0% complete

              Name : Server:0
              UUID : d9b2f19f:01d7ce88:c46d2dd3:c1ab05f0
            Events : 63711

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8      145        0      active sync set-A   /dev/sdj1
       1       8      129        1      active sync set-B   /dev/sdi1
       2      65        1        2      active sync set-A   /dev/sdq1
       3       8      225        3      active sync set-B   /dev/sdo1
       4       8      177        4      active sync set-A   /dev/sdl1
       5       8      209        5      active sync set-B   /dev/sdn1
       6       8      193        6      active sync set-A   /dev/sdm1
       7       8      241        7      active sync set-B   /dev/sdp1
      15       8       33        8      active sync set-A   /dev/sdc1
      14       8       65        9      active sync set-B   /dev/sde1
      13       8       97       10      active sync set-A   /dev/sdg1
      12       8       17       11      active sync set-B   /dev/sdb1
      11       8        1       12      active sync set-A   /dev/sda1
      10       8       49       13      active sync set-B   /dev/sdd1
       9       8      113       14      active sync set-A   /dev/sdh1
```

Comment: When the array kicks a drive out, it won't write that drive's metadata superblock.  The drives that were kicked out will still show what the array membership was at that time (e.g. "AAAAAAAA...", or the sound you were making when you saw that!) 
 In your case, you know that when the array advanced from 63706 to 63707, it kicked all those drives out.  After that, two more events happened - probably just mounting the filesystem or something - to get the array to 63709.  Take a look at the kernel's journal, or even /var/log/messages - there might be something in there!

Comment: It may be that the array was assembled without those drives, or it could be that they dropped off at some point.